# Update Changed Assembly Version Number TFS Build

Tags: powershell, tfs, build-process, tfsbuild

I'd like to be able to automatically update the assembly version off all changed projects on a TFS check-in.  We'd like to do this as part of our gated check-in so that developers don't have to remember to manually update those numbers on every check-in.

My current approach would be to:

1. Determine what projects contains changes on check-in
2. Check out the AssemblyInfo.cs in each project with changes
3. Increment the version number in each AssemblyInfo.cs file
4. Begin build process

I assume there is a way to accomplish this using a combination of PowerShell and customizing the TFS build template, but have little familiarity with either.  Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Use the script located [here](https://github.com/cfbarbero/TFSBuild/blob/master/ApplyVersionToAssemblies.ps1) as a pre-build script in your build template.

The script will change all AssemblyInfo.cs files that are found with the build number.

Answer (score 2):

How to update assembly version of your projects using PowerShell scripts. A very good guide.

The answer is bit late but you can find a good guide [here](https://asimplify.com/powershell-how-to-update-assemblyversions-of-net-projects-using-ps-script/) , Have a look into that